# Deterministic Finite Automata

Tags: automata, dfa

I am new to automata theory. This question below is for practice:

Let there be a language that is made of words that start and end with different symbols and have the alphabet {0,1}. For example, 001, 10110101010100, 10 and 01 are all accepted. But 101, 1, 0, and 1010001101 are rejected.

How do I:

Construct a Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) diagram?

Find the regular expression for the DFA?

I tried to post an image of the DFA I drew, but I need 10 reputations to post images unfortunately, which I do not yet have.

Comment: What do you have so far for the regex?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theoretical computer science, which is more appropriate at cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Christopher --  by regex, I am assuming you mean the regular expression? I did not yet have anything for that as I was trying to work in the order of the question. But apparently as Tharindu has stated below it's easier to get the regex first.

Comment: @templeplatetypedef - I did not know about cs.stackexchange.com. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, I think it's easier to identify the regular expression first.

**Regular Expression**

```
1(1|0)*0 | 0(1|0)*1
```

(* denotes Kleene's star operation)

Now we convert this regular expression into an equivalent finite automata.

**Constructing a DFA**

You can design the NFA-∧(or NFA-ε in some texts) easily using Thompson constructors[1] for a given language(regex) which is then converted into an NFA without lambda transitions. 
This NFA can then be mapped to an equivalent DFA using subset construction method. [2]

If you want, you can further reduce this DFA to obtain a minimal DFA which is unique for a given regular language. (Myhill-Nerode theorem) [3]

Regex → NFA-∧ → NFA → DFA → DFA(minimal),
This is the standard procedure.

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm

[2] http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node9.html

[3]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem

Comment: This works if ε is not in the set of valid words. OP - can you have the empty string?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, the fact whether we are accepting or rejecting the null string depends on the convention we adopt. According to the language description, ε is not in the language because ε does not start and end with different symbols.

Comment: @TharinduRusira, thanks for your  help. Although I do not know what NFA-^ stands for.

Comment: @TharinduRusira, can you break down how you got to that regular expression? For example, I think that 1(1|0)*0 means the expression has to start with 1, it can then be followed by either a 1 or a 0, and it has to end with a 0, which we know can repeat because of the * notation. Same logic would follow for 0(1|0)*1. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @silverlight, yes you got it right. Obtaining the regular expression is kind of intuitive. In your case, there can be only two possibilities. (1) Start with 1, any combination of 1 and 0 in the middle and end with 0. (2)Start with 0, any combination of 1 and 0 in the middle and end with 1. 
Precisely, * notation says zero or more occurrences of a given symbol/string.
 
NFA-∧ is a fancy notation to represent a regular NFA with transitions for the "null" string input. (I assume you know what an NFA is)

Answer (score 0):

We can get two possibilities here- 
1) String starts with 0 and ends with 1 => [0(0|1)*1]
2) Strings staring with 1 and ending with 0 => [1(0|1)*0]
Also from rejected strings we know that minimum length would be 2.

Therefore final expression would be [0(0|1)*1]|[1(0|1)*0]
 NFA would be something like this

[NFA for given language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKgv.jpg)